# Trouble accessing $this in controller method

Tags: php, slim

I'm building an API via Slim, and using class based controller methods. Looking at the [router docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html) (under "Allow Slim to instantiate the controller"), it seems like the DI should insert the `ContainerInterface` into the class constructor, and then I should be able to access `$this->container` in the class method to access the container.

I created a base class:

```
class BaseController
{

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(\Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

}
```

And then tried this:

```
class PMsController extends BaseController
{

    public function index(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
        var_dump($this); exit;
    }

}
```

And my route:

```
$app->group('/pms', function () {
    $this->get('', '\App\Controllers\PMsController::index');
})->add(authMiddlware());
```

But I get the error: `Using $this when not in object context`. I have no idea how that gets there, when it's a class method. I'm not positive if I should be using another method of accessing the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your route to

```
$app->group('/pms', function () {
    $this->get('', '\App\Controllers\PMsController:index');
})->add(authMiddlware());
```

Please note the single `:` rather than using double `::`. You also don't need a BaseController if you aren't performing any additional feature in it. Slim 3 will inject the `Container` by default for you.

Comment: Of course I make a simple stupid mistake. Every other one of my routes has a single `:`, but I put two here... And I'll take a look at the class sans the BaseController; I may need it later, but for now I just want the container.

Comment: Hm... If I get rid of my `BaseController` and I dump `$this`, it's empty. Doesn't seem like it auto injects?